# PHP DOM: How to get wrapper tags with attributes for a text node?

Tags: php, html, dom

I would like to get the wrapper tags for a text node. Given such an arbitrary html

```
<html><body>
<p>salalala</p>
<ul><li>hehehe</li></ul>
<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    <span style="cufon whatever blablabla">
    Capture this text 1
    </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    text 2
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to get the wrapper tags for "Capture this text 1" that are

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    <span style="cufon whatever blablabla">
```

This is just for demo, they can be anything, but given a text match, how can I retrieve the wrapper tags?

I have been thinking of using php dom, and step through the tree to find the textnode, and working back from that. I am unsure how the wrapper tags could be extracted though.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
//print_r($doc->childNodes);

print_children($doc);


function print_children($object){

    if ($object->nodeName == "#text" AND strpos("Capture this text 1",trim($object->data)) !== false) {
        print "Parent: ";
        print_r($object->parentNode);
        }

    foreach($object->childNodes as $child) {
    print_r($child);
    print_children($child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use fsockopen to retrieve some HTML in some website i want. This is my current function how to do that.

```
$server  = 'www.somesite.com';  // or an IP address
$port    = 80;

function getTextFromHTML($server, $port, $timeout=100){
    $socket  = fsockopen( $server, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout );
    fputs( $socket, $request );
    if ( $size > 0 ) {
        $start_el = 'div class="main">';
        $stop_el = '</div>';
        $f_start = false;
        $f_stop = false;

        $tmp="";
        while (!feof($socket))
        {
            $buffer = fgets($socket,$size);
            if(!$f_start){
                $strpos = mb_strpos($buffer, $start_el);
                if ($strpos !== false)
                {
                    $buffer = mb_substr($buffer, $strpos, $size);
                    $f_start = true;
                }
            }

            if ($f_start && !$f_stop)
            {
                $strpos = mb_strpos($buffer, $stop_el);
                if ($strpos !== false)
                {
                    $f_stop = true;
                }
                $tmp .= $buffer;
            }
        }               

    }       
    fclose( $socket );
    return $tmp;
}
```

you just need some configuration in the $start_el and $stop_el.

Hope this'll help you to get a point to your problem